# How to get full url value separately in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a system where user clicks on a link which has two ids from separate table from database separated by `/` like shown below. How can I create variable in jquery to access both ids.

I mean, I can access first $items->id by creating variable id by below jquery but how can I get value of $items->set_id to put into the variable.

```js
$(".revert").on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $("a[data-id=" + id + "]").closest("tr").hide();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "hold_req/" + id,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#msg').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
      $('#msg').html("Requested").fadeIn('slow') //also show a success message 
      $('#msg').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" data-id={{$items->id}}/{{$items->set_id}}" class="revert btn btn-info">Revert</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does `click on the is a link with have two ids` mean? Please change the snippet I made to a [mcve] without templating - this is not a laravel question

Comment: Also why so complicated? `$("a[data-id=" + id + "]").closest("tr").hide();` just do `$(this).closest("tr").hide();`

Comment: Is it clear now @mplungjan.

Comment: I updated your text. I think it is clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split("/")` then access value using `id[0]` for id and `id[1]` for set-id . Another way , why not simply add another data-attribute i.e : `data-set-id="{{$items->set_id}}"` and access it using `$(this).data('set-id')`.

***Demo Code***:

```js
$(".revert").on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id').split("/");
  console.log(id[0])
  console.log(id[1])
  console.log($(this).data('set-id'))
  //your ajax...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <!--add another data-attr-->
      <a href="#" data-id="{{$items->id}}/{{$items->set_id}}" data-set-id="{{$items->set_id}}" class="revert btn btn-info">Revert</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hmm... it is easier to add new data-set-id as you suggested...thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I is not yet quite clear to me what you want. Maybe the following can be helpful?

```js
$(".revert").on('click', function() {
  var id_and_type = $(this).attr('data-id'), [id,type]=id_and_type.split("/");
  $(this).closest("tr").hide();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET", dataType:"text",
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/"+id_and_type,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#data').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
      $('#msg').html("Requested "+id+", result type: "+type).fadeIn('slow') //also show a success message 
      $('#msg').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr><td><a href="#" data-id="1/posts" class="revert btn btn-info">Revert1</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="#" data-id="2/comments" class="revert btn btn-info">Revert2</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="#" data-id="3/posts" class="revert btn btn-info">Revert3</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="#" data-id="4/comments" class="revert btn btn-info">Revert4</a></td></tr>
</table>

<div id="msg"></div>
Data:
<div id="data"></div>
```

Comment: And something like `url: \`hold_req/${id}/${setid}\``